# Let $N$ be the $44$-digit number $44 \cdots 44$. Compute the remainder when $\sum^{2021}_{n=0} 10^{2^n}$ is divided by $N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Question: Let $N$ be the $44$-digit number $44\cdots 44$. Compute the remainder when $$\sum^{2021}_{n=0} 10^{2^n}$$ is divided by $N$.

No idea how to really start off here. I observed that $2021=43 \cdot 47$, and that $44 \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$.

Using Fermat’s little theorem, I know that $2^{42} \equiv 1 \pmod{43}$. I was thinking I could use this in the coefficients, but because $N$ isn’t just $43$, it’s not as easy as reducing the exponents and maybe finding a pattern.

Rewriting $N$ as $\frac{4}{9}(10^{44}-1)$ using the formula for the sum of a geometric series wasn’t of much help either.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Hint: Apply Chinese Reminder Theorem.  Show that $10^{2^n} $ cycles through a few values mod $10^{44} - 1 $. $\quad$ Further hint: Try 44, 444, 4444 first, and the fact that there is a pattern should start to appear.

Comment: I was alluding to what you observed. I didn't get $\sum 10^{4n}$. I only sum over the exponents of $4, 8, 16, 24, 32 $. Can you recheck, or provide your solution and I can review? $\quad$ Show that $10^{2^n } \pmod{\frac{10^{44} - 1 } { 9 }} $ cycles through the values $10^1, 10^2, 10^4, 10^8, 10^{16}, 10^{32}, 10^{24}, 10^{4}, 10^{8} \ldots $

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm not sure what the pattern you were alluding to with 444 and 4444 was, but I managed to deduce that $10^{2^n} \equiv 10^{2^n \pmod{44}} \pmod{10^{44}-1}$. After using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, I got an answer of $110+202\sum^{10}_{n=1} 10^{4n}=2020202020202020202020202020202020202020110$. (apologies for sending this after your comment, I made a typo and I fixed it after you commented).

Comment: @CalvinLin I got that it cycles through $10^1, 10^2, 10^4, 10^8, 10^{16}, 10^{32}, 10^{20}, 10^{40}, 10^{36}, 10^{28}, 10^{12}, 10^{24}, 10^{4}, \cdots$. I'll check my computations again right now.

Comment: Oh, I had an arithmetic error, after $10^{32}$ does come $10^{20}$. Your calculations are correct. I agree with your expression now.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll write a solution in the morning, it's getting late now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that: $$N=4+4 \cdot 10+4\cdot 10^2+\cdots+4\cdot 10^{43}=\sum^{43}_{n=0} 4 \cdot 10^n=\frac{4}{9}(10^{44}-1)$$

We consider taking $10^{2^n}$ modulo $(10^{44}-1)$ for $n=0,1,2,\cdots 2021$.

- If $n=0,1,2,3,4,5$, then $10^{2^n} \equiv 10^{2^n} \pmod{10^{44}-1}$.
- If $n=6$, then $10^{64}=10^{20}(10^{44}-1)+10^{20} \equiv 10^{20} \pmod{10^{44}-1}$.
- If $n=7$, then $10^{128}=10^{84}(10^{44}-1)+10^{40}(10^{44}-1)+10^{40} \equiv 10^{40} \pmod{10^{44}-1}$.

In general, we see that $10^{2^n} \equiv 10^{2^n \pmod{44}} \pmod{10^{44}-1}$.

Considering $2^n \pmod{44}$, we see that it cycles through the values $1,2,4,8,16,32,20,40,36,28,12,24,4\cdots$, where the repeating part $4,8,16,32,20,40,36,28,12,24$ has a length of $10$.

Therefore, we can say that $$\sum^{2021}_{n=0} 10^{2^n} \equiv \left[10^1+10^2+202 \cdot \sum^{10}_{n=1} 10^{4n} \right] \pmod{10^{44}-1}$$

Taking $\sum^{2021}_{n=0} 10^{2^n}$ modulo $4$, it is clear that if $n=0$, then $10^{2^n} \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$, and that if $n \geq 1$, then $10^{2^n} \equiv 0 \mod{4}$.

Solving this system of congruences using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $$\sum^{2021}_{n=0} 10^{2^n} \equiv \left[ 10^1+10^2+202 \cdot \sum^{10}_{n=1} 10^{4n} \right] \pmod{4(10^{44}-1)}$$

Therefore, we can say that $$\sum^{2021}_{n=0} 10^{2^n} \equiv \boxed{\left[ 10^1+10^2+202 \cdot \sum^{10}_{n=1} 10^{4n} \right]} \pmod{N}$$

The decimal representation of this remainder is $$2020202020202020202020202020202020202020110$$